# JayData V1.5.6 oData v3

Tags: javascript, react-native, odata, jaydata

I building a React-Native App and want to use JayData to consume oData v3. But the newest Version which I can only use because I can use it with React-Native doesnt support v3 anymore... Is there a way to get it work with v3?

Thanks and Kind Regards,
Christoph Girmm

Answer (score 0):

You can consume OData v3 services with [JayData 1.3.6](http://jaydata.codeplex.com/releases/view/118964). The latest version supports only v4 format.